# Como aplicar efeitos parecidos com o Blur à imagens e que funcione fora do Chrome?

Tags: css, css3, imagem, edição-de-imagens

Ao tentar aplicar o efeito *Blur* em imagens, tive problemas com alguns navegadores, como podem ver no link que segue abaixo.

[EFEITO BLUR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17311/efeito-blur-em-diferentes-navegadores)

Gostaria de saber se há algum efeito que se assemelhe ao *Blur* e que funcione nos navegadores mais modernos (Firefox, Chrome, IE e Safari).

OBS: A resposta dada a essa pergunta citada acima usa uma imagem que já está com efeito *Blur*, e não é oque eu quero. A proposta é usar propriedades CSS para fazê-lo.